# python google cloud metrics hangs forever

Tags: python, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a python module that queries google metrics.  It works perfectly fine if I run it as a script on command line, but if I import it into another module and try to call the functions in it, it just hangs forever with no error messages.

In module gmetrics.py

```
import time
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
from google.oauth2 import service_account


def get_gmetrics():
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(MY_CREDS_FILE)
    client = monitoring_v3.services.metric_service.MetricServiceClient(credentials=creds)

    instance = MY_INSTANCE
    projectName = f"projects/{MY_PROJECT}"
    now = time.time()
    seconds = int(now)
    nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
    interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
        {
            "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
            "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 1200), "nanos": nanos},
        }
    )
    filter = f'metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization" AND \
            metric.labels.instance_name = "{instance}"'

    results = client.list_time_series(
        request={
            "name": projectName,
            "filter": filter,
            "interval": interval,
            "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
        }
    )
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_gmetrics()
```

If I run this command line like so:

python3 gmetrics.py

It runs just fine and I get data from the call.  But if I import the module into another module and try to call gmetrics.get_metrics(), it hangs forever.  Without any errors in the error log, I'm at a loss of what could be wrong.

Comment: Did you investigate till what point inside the function are the snippets executed? What I mean is does your function pause at client.list_time_series or before?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention where it hangs.  It hangs at the client.list_time_series call.